# Add HTML entity with ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree, html-entities

I'm generating some HTML using ElementTree in a Python script. The relevant part looks like this:

```py
separator = ET.SubElement(toc, 'span')
separator.set('class', 'separator')
separator.text = u"&nbsp;⬩"
```

The problem is that the HTML entity `&nbsp;` is being encoded in the resulting XML output as `&amp;nbsp;`, which puts the literal text `&nbsp;` on the rendered web page, instead of inserting a non-breaking space.

I'm working around it by escaping a non-breaking space into the Python string like this: `u"\u00A0⬩"`. This puts a literal non-breaking space in my HTML instead of the entity. Ultimately, it works because it is faithfully rendered as a non-breaking space, but it makes the source code hard to read because a non-breaking space looks like a regular space.

How can I get ElementTree to insert an HTML entity into my source code?

Comment: XML doesn't support entities except for quote, apostrophe, ampersand, and angle brackets.  The rest are an HTML extension.  You may need to find another tool.

Comment: Not sure what can be done about this. All `&` characters are replaced by `&amp;` during serialization (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L2040). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/9276848/407651. lxml behaves in a similar way: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67299346/407651.

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7986272/407651